# Adding images inside console pycharm

Tags: python, image, pycharm, display

I'm a beginner in python. I'd like to know how I can get images inside my console without creating an external window in which to view the image. I'm creating a multiple-choice questionnaire that uses images to answer, so it should display images when the question is asked. I've tried PIL and CV2, but images keeps popping out to an external window. Is there a way to display the image inside the console?

For example:

---

**Which of the following images is a bicycle?**

- A. image.jpg (image should displayed)
- B. image2.jpg (image should be displayed)
- C. image3.jpg (image should be displayed)

Comment: Okay, from what I think:
Is it that you want the images to display along with the gui when you open the interface (class), without clicking on any button to  open a file dialog for one to upload images?

If what I'm thinking is what you want, then use this pattern:
        
        ```self.imageLabel.setPixmap(QPixmap("write the path to your photo and include the extension")```

Comment: Exactly, should I install PyQT to run those commands? How I can share my code with you as I'm just doing it for fun as I just recently enrolled for python and seeing what I've learned and space on replies is quite little

Comment: pip install PyQt5, then import the necessary libraries into your program.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use Jupyter notebooks. The code lines in it are written in code cells and can be executed within the notebook.

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/jupyter-notebook-support.html

[image]